# Can I change background image behind the tabs in TabActivity?

Tags: android, android-widget

Can I change background image behind the tabs in TabActivity ? I changed images of tab buttons ( created selector ), but hot to change image behing those buttons ? I have three tab buttons and and I need to put half circle behind buttons. I tried to add

android:background="@drawable/circle" inside TabWidget but it doesn't help. What to do ?

Comment: As soon as you start to want to customize tabs your doomed :D this is really troublesome to do (in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

By implementing custom tabs, you can achieve this. Check this:

[Custom Android Tabs](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)